# Video viewer on php

Tags: php, video, curl, bots

I'm trying to make a flash video viewer on PHP. But the video's statistic isn't increasing.
Autoplay is on.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $video_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $random_browser);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $random_proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What is a mistake? Are there any solutions? Does it matter to use `echo` function?

Comment: Why do you need to enclose the variables `$video_url` and `$random_proxy` in double quotes ? You can remove the quotes. They are not necessary.

Comment: If you don't print something you won't have output. BTW, it's not quite clear to me what `make a flash video viewer on PHP` means. You have web service and from this web service you get data for your flash application?

Comment: I'm getting a web page with embed flash video

Comment: It means I need to cheat view's statistic

Comment: First of all, you need to figure how their statistic works. Do multiple views of the same user count or not? Maybe it increased once on first request and not on subsequent? Maybe it's bound to IP (try connecting via proxy) or cookies (add cookie handling to curl)

Comment: I'm using the proxies list and the browsers list. I run it using CRON every 10 min, but views don't grow.